# magento version 2.1.13 error using xampp

Tags: php, mysql, magento

i am new to magento and i am trying to install magento on my local server i.e. xampp. So when i am installing it some error's are been produced which i am not able to solve it .So error's are as:

1) Your PHP version is 7.2.5. The required PHP version is ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6. 
 2) PHP Extension mcrypt.

I am using magento version 2.1.13 and php version 7.2.5.
I have searched a lot but this error is not solved anywhere so please anyone could help me out.
 I am trying to install magento on apache version:
Apache/2.4.33 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0h PHP/7.2.5

and php version is 7.2.5

Comment: do you have php set up so you can use it at cli-level? if so, do this: php -v or create a phpinfo.php file with the contents `<?php phpinfo();` in your magento root and navigate to localhost/phpinfo.php - it might show a different php version to what you're expecting

Comment: you need to install mcrypt extension in xampp

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs sorry but i am not able to get you so please can you elaborate your answer as i totally new to it

Comment: @Dave i have installed it

Comment: @bobbygotecha ok, so try this: open cmd and type `php -v` - should return php version. And try creating a file called `phpinfo.php` in your Magento installation `C:\www\magento` for instance with the following contents: `<?php phpinfo();` then, in your browser go to `mysite.local/phpinfo.php` where `mysite.local` is your localhost

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs yes i created a file and when i executed it ,it returned http://localhost/dashboard/phpinfo.php

Comment: but error is as it is

Comment: it shouldn't error at all as it has nothing to do with Magento - should just display php information :)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs yes it displays the information about php

Comment: so next how can i solve magento error??

Comment: @bobbygotecha now find what version of php it has in the info box - check it's as expected

Comment: how to solve my php version error and mcrypt error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172986/discussion-between-bobby-gotecha-and-thisguyhastwothumbs).